# instagram login on an iOS app built on Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, parse-platform, instagram

I am trying to implement instagram login on my iOS app which is based on Parse. I was not able to get the oath token from parse that I use of the login. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your code? take a look at these [tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) from parse

Comment: There's not sufficient details in your question to get a good grasp of where you're stuck. A good place to start is http://blog.parse.com/2013/12/03/bring-your-own-login/